# Explicit form of intersection of two ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $J=\langle y^2-x^4,y^2-y^3-2y^2x-yx^2+y^2x^2+2yx^3\rangle\subseteq \Bbb{C}[x,y]$. Find $\sqrt{J}$.

I'm using nullstellensatz to find $\sqrt{J}$. Finding $I(V(J))$ I was able to deduce that $\sqrt{J}=\langle x-1,y+1\rangle\cap\langle y-x^2\rangle$. Now I want to find a more explicit form. I suspect that $\langle x-1,y+1\rangle\cap\langle y-x^2\rangle=\langle (y-x^2)(x-1),(y-x^2)(y+1)\rangle$, but I was only able to conclude one inclusion (the obvious one that the right side is included in the left one).

Is it even true?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true. Let $J_1 = \langle x-1,y+1\rangle$ and $J_2 = \langle y-x^2 \rangle$ be the two ideals. The intersection $J_1 \cap J_2$ equals the product $J_1 \cdot J_2$ because the ideals are comaximal: $J_1 + J_2 = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

They are comaximal because $- (y+1) + (x+1)(x-1) + (y-x^2)=-2 \in J_1+J_2$.

The product equals the intersection for comaximal ideals in a commutative ring, because $$J_1 \cap J_2 = (J_1 \cap J_2)\cdot\mathbb{C}[x,y]=(J_1\cap J_2)\cdot(J_1+J_2)=(J_1 \cap J_2)\cdot J_1 + (J_1 \cap J_2)\cdot J_2 \subseteq J_2 \cdot J_1 + J_1\cdot J_2=J_1\cdot J_2$$

and the inclusion in the other direction holds for all ideals.

Comment: I suspected they were comaximal but couldn't reach the right combination. Thanks!

Comment: @GBA There is no need to find "the right combination": $J_1$ is maximal and $y-x^2\notin J_1$, so thier sum is the whole ring.

Comment: @user26857 Is it obvious that it's not contained in it?

Comment: Of course it is! A polynomial $f$ belongs to $J_1$ iff $f(1,-1)=0$.